# Why is this gradient invalid?(theano)

Tags: python-3.x, theano

I wonder why below code is invalid..

```
from numpy import *
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dmatrix("x")
mx = x[...,None,:]
a = T.ones((1,3))
T.grad(mx[...,0].dot(a).sum(), a).eval({x:ones((5,10)).astype(float32)})
```

below error emerged:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/yu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    883             outputs =\
--> 884                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    885                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)

ValueError: Shape mismatch: A.shape[1] != x.shape[0]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-52410617594a> in <module>()
      3 mx = x[...,None,:]
      4 a = T.ones((1,3))
----> 5 T.grad(mx[...,0].dot(a).sum(), a).eval({x:ones((5,10)).astype(float32)})

/home/yu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gof/graph.py in eval(self, inputs_to_values)
    517         args = [inputs_to_values[param] for param in inputs]
    518 
--> 519         rval = self._fn_cache[inputs](*args)
    520 
    521         return rval

/home/yu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    896                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    897                     thunk=thunk,
--> 898                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    899             else:
    900                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

/home/yu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    323         # extra long error message in that case.
    324         pass
--> 325     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    326 
    327 

/home/yu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    683             value = tp()
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value
    687 

/home/yu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    882         try:
    883             outputs =\
--> 884                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    885                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)
    886         except Exception:

ValueError: Shape mismatch: A.shape[1] != x.shape[0]
Apply node that caused the error: CGemv{inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float64'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Rebroadcast{0}.0, TensorConstant{0.0})
Toposort index: 7
Inputs types: [TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(float64, scalar), TensorType(float64, matrix), TensorType(float64, vector), TensorType(float64, scalar)]
Inputs shapes: [(3,), (), (3, 5), (1,), ()]
Inputs strides: [(8,), (), (8, 24), (80,), ()]
Inputs values: [array([  0.00000000e+000,   4.94065646e-324,   9.88131292e-324]), array(1.0), 'not shown', array([ 1.]), array(0.0)]
Inputs type_num: [12, 12, 12, 12, 12]
Outputs clients: [[InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}(CGemv{inplace}.0)]]

Debugprint of the apply node: 
CGemv{inplace} [id A] <TensorType(float64, vector)> ''   
 |AllocEmpty{dtype='float64'} [id B] <TensorType(float64, vector)> ''   
 | |TensorConstant{3} [id C] <TensorType(int64, scalar)>
 |TensorConstant{1.0} [id D] <TensorType(float64, scalar)>
 |InplaceDimShuffle{1,0} [id E] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''   
 | |Alloc [id F] <TensorType(float64, matrix)> ''   
 |   |TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 1.0} [id G] <TensorType(float64, (True, True))>
 |   |Shape_i{0} [id H] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''   
 |   | |x [id I] <TensorType(float64, matrix)>
 |   |TensorConstant{3} [id C] <TensorType(int64, scalar)>
 |Rebroadcast{0} [id J] <TensorType(float64, vector)> ''   
 | |Subtensor{int8, ::, int64} [id K] <TensorType(float64, (True,))> ''   
 |   |InplaceDimShuffle{0,x,1} [id L] <TensorType(float64, (False, True, False))> ''   
 |   | |x [id I] <TensorType(float64, matrix)>
 |   |Constant{0} [id M] <int8>
 |   |Constant{0} [id N] <int64>
 |TensorConstant{0.0} [id O] <TensorType(float64, scalar)>

Storage map footprint:
 - x, Input, Shape: (5, 10), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 400 Byte(s)
 - InplaceDimShuffle{0,x,1}.0, Shape: (5, 1, 10), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 400 Byte(s)
 - Alloc.0, Shape: (5, 3), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 120 Byte(s)
 - InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, Shape: (3, 5), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 120 Byte(s)
 - AllocEmpty{dtype='float64'}.0, Shape: (3,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 24 Byte(s)
 - Subtensor{int8, ::, int64}.0, Shape: (1,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - Shape_i{0}.0, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{1.0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{0.0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - Constant{0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - Rebroadcast{0}.0, Shape: (1,), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{3}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8.0 Byte(s)
 - TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 1.0}, Shape: (1, 1), ElemSize: 8 Byte(s), TotalSize: 8 Byte(s)
 - Constant{0}, Shape: (), ElemSize: 1 Byte(s), TotalSize: 1.0 Byte(s)
 TotalSize: 593.0 Byte(s) 0.000 GB
 TotalSize inputs: 441.0 Byte(s) 0.000 GB

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I thought above script includes broadcasted operation was wrong,
So no broadcasting used before gradient operation as follows,

```
x = T.tensor3("x")
mx = x
a = T.ones((1,3))
T.grad(mx[...,0].dot(a).sum(), a).eval({x:ones((5,1,10)).astype(float32)})
```

successfully performed and dumped bellow result.

```
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.]], dtype=float32)
```

But why is the former case invalid?
Is the gradient with broadcasting mathmatically invalid?
Why does shape miss much happen on gradient?

Could you teach me about above question?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be the reason why that is so
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/JKyNcQQJZDU